# React Native cached error cannot read property getScrollableNode of undefined

Tags: caching, error-handling, react-native

While working in a React Native component yesterday (probably cowboy coding a little too much) I encountered this error:

```
cannot read property getScrollableNode of undefined
```

after removing all the code that caused this error I am still getting the error anytime I introduce an error.  It seems like the error is being cached somewhere.

On the client side I've tried deleting and reinstalling `node modules`, `watchman watch-del-all` and `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`

Any other suggestions to solve or theories on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you encounter this issue on Android, iOS or both?

Comment: I was encountering the error in iOS. Haven't used Android much so I'm not sure if is the same kind of error in Android.  I've found this error occurs frequently with uncaught RN errors and I believe it is usually the result of having components with some kind of error that cannot properly mount and are nested in a scrollView or listView.  Occasionally I swear I also still get errors after I've made the appropriate fixes (or rolled all changes back) so I still think some things are cached but I could be very wrong on that one.

Answer (score 5):

I've found this to generally be a secondary-error which appears as a result of another error earlier in the rendering process. Check your error log (browser debug console, device log, etc) and you should see a more specific error describing what's going wrong.